# Checking if value already exists in different sheets and creating a results table mixing them

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that works over different tables like this (lets call them x y and z):

```
  x
------------
a 0 
b 1  
c 2  

  y
------------
a 3 
b 1  
c 2 

  z
------------
a 3 
b 1  
c 0
```

and I need a results table like this (table is already made, just fill):

```
  x  y  z
------------
a 0  1  2
b 3  1  2
c 3  1  0
```

What do I need? When scanning tables, "a b and c" will be repeated. I need to print every result without creating in that column extra set of data.

**I don't want:**

```
  x  y  z
------------
a 0    
b 1 
c 2     
a    3  
b    1  
c    2  
a       3
b       1
c       0
```

How can I achieve this?

To assign values in the correct rows I got this loop as a control of the current row:

```
Sub LoopRange()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Hoja1.Range("B17:B30")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    'MsgBox rCell.row'

Next rCell

End Sub
```

How can I extract te value of (a , b and c) so I can compare strings with my results sheet?

Final excel structure should be like this:

[image: Excel estructure]

Comment: I've tried scanning the ranges and checking if value exists, but didn't work, will update my original question with examples. @pnuts data is flexible, in this case is just an example.

Comment: I don't think that fits my needings, data is dynamic.

Comment: Try the Offset function. In your For-Next loop, `rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value` will give you the value of whatever is in column A.

Comment: You say you have a result table already created. What row and column is the top left corner?

Comment: @dev1998 left row (a b c) is data that is going to repeat, x y z is every sheet that contains again a b c with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is working for me. If you step through with the debugger you'll be able to see what it is doing and modify it in case I made some assumptions that were incorrect.

I pulled the data from a worksheet named Hoja1. I wrote to a worksheet named xyz_result. I assumed that the x, y, and z column headers were already in place in B1:D1. I also assumed that the a, b, c row names were in place in A2:A4

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rRng2 As Range

    Dim Wbk As Workbook

    Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook


    Worksheets("Hoja1").Activate
    Dim currentTable As String
    Dim abcValue As String
    Dim currentValue As String

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer



    'Set rngMyRange = .Range(.Range("a1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Set rRng = Range("B17:B30")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        If Len(Trim(rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value)) = 0 Then  ' It might be to the left of text such as x, y, or z
            If Len(Trim(rCell.Value)) > 0 Then ' It is text such as x, y, or z
                currentTable = rCell.Value
            End If
        End If

        If Len(Trim(rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value)) > 0 Then 
            abcValue = rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            currentValue = rCell.Value
        End If


        If Len(currentTable) > 0 And Len(abcValue) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("xyz_Result").Activate
            Set c = Range("A1:D4").Find(abcValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
            rowNum = c.row
            Set r = Range("A1:D4").Find(currentTable, LookIn:=xlValues)
            colNum = r.Column
            Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value = currentValue
        End If

        Worksheets("Hoja1").Activate


    Next rCell

 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It works thanks. I will accept the answers as correct later since I can adapt it to what I need. The main problem here is that I need the macro to write the "abc" manually in "xyz_Result" since "abc" can be "abcdefg" in a future (dynamic data). Also a small clarification, x, y z should be in different sheets, check my original post to see what I mean.